# Meteor w/Google Analytics not reporting

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I have a Meteor app in production using a Cordova plugin for Google Analytics.  The existing Cordova plugin works well and we have Real Time GA reports. We are about to release the web platform of the app, so I've removed the Cordova GA plugin in favor of a Meteor package that will work on all platforms.

Using the same tracking code, I have tried reywood:iron-router-ga, okgrow:analytics, datariot:ganalytics, and the raw Google code. I can get them all to work, from the standpoint that the GA Debugger in Firefox and Chrome show they are all sending correctly. However, NONE of them show up on the GA Real Time reports. I have been at this for two days and am feeling pretty stupid at this point.

I've been through pages of searches and found no solution. Any thoughts for a weary developer?
UPDATE: I Installed reywood:iron-router-ga and my settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "public" : {
    "ga": {
      "id":"UA-450xxxxx-y"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using a build command with --settings settings.json, and I made a METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable on my Modulus project with the same json.

My send command looks like this on the client:

```
ga("send","event",evCat,evName);
```

I'm not using any sends from the server.

As I said earlier, the GA Debugger in both Chrome and Firefox show the appropriate beacons being sent.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I've successfully gotten `okgrow:analytics` working. It's hard to know what's going on without seeing some of your code, though. Post some relevant stuff up, and be sure to specify whether the code is client or server or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out none of my GA package installs were the problem. The entire problem was that my GA View (on the GA admin page) was a mobile app view, which worked fine when my GA tracker package was in Cordova. But when I removed the cordova package and added a Meteor package, GA stopped accepting the beacons because they were for website views. So I just added another GA View in my GA property that was for website data. That new view now shows web and mobile platform data because the GA beacons are being sent from the Meteor app whether you're running on a browser or a device.

Comment: i am using reywood:iron-router-ga for google analytics, it works well with the Web but when i run my same app on mobile app it does not show any Real time analytics. Can u help me that what i am missing in my GA admin View for mobiles